# Android - Cannot modify widgets in DialogFragment view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment, `DieConfig`, which displays 2 SeekBars. I have a TextView next to each SeekBar which I want to display the current value of the relevant bar. To do this, I am using `SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener` in my DialogFragment's `onCreateView`. However, there doesn't seem to be any effect.

I have tried editing other widgets, such as TextViews however these are not modified either, and I also tried placing the code in onCreateDialog (which throws a nullPointerException) and onViewCreated (which has the same problem as onCreateView).

My code to set the listener is as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("tech.gaskell.diceroller","[Debug1425] onCreateView ran");
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_die_config, container);

    SeekBar count_bar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.die_config_count_bar);
    SeekBar sides_bar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.die_config_sides_bar);
    TextView sometext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.die_config_count_label);
    sometext.setText("So this does run");

    count_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.d("tech.gaskell.diceroller","[Debug1425] onProgressChanged ran");
            /*int actualValue = progress + 1;

            TextView value_textview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.die_config_count_count);
            value_textview.setText(String.valueOf(actualValue));*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    });

    sides_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.d("tech.gaskell.diceroller","[Debug1425] onProgressChanged ran");
            int actualValue = progress + 2;

            TextView value_textview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.die_config_sides_count);
            value_textview.setText(String.valueOf(actualValue));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    });
    Log.d("tech.gaskell.diceroller","[Debug1425] about to return from onCreateView");
    return view;
}
```

The logcat indicates that onCreateView runs, however the TextView doesn't change as it should and the listeners aren't set.

What is preventing this code from having any effect?

Comment: You need to update your UI inside `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`

Comment: @FrancescoBocci I have already tried that, as I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with another DialogFragment. I have tried using `onViewCreated` and `onCreateView`, both which run without errors, however any changes to widgets in the view don't persist.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question. Try to create this `TextView value_textview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.die_config_sides_count);` inside `onCreateView`. Then, inside `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`, change text

Comment: @FrancescoBocci the problem is that running `.setOnSeekBarChangeListener` has no effect whatsoever. No matter what I write inside there, it has 0 effect on the app when it runs.